# FullCalendar Refresh issue with JSON php file

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar

I have an issue with fullCalendar and what i want is when you do save through a button it will call ajax and save the changes to the database and then refresh all the events.

So my problem is following:
- My php file contain the all events reading from db but that events are not displaying at all.:(
Following is my json_event.php file

```
$driver_booking = q("select * from booking where vehicle_id = ".$_REQUEST['ch']);
                $array = array();
                foreach($driver_booking as $bookings) {
                    $driver = getRow("driver", $bookings['driver_id']);
                    //return date_time from only....
                    $date_from = date("Y-m-d",$bookings['datetime_from']);
                    $time_from = date("H:i:s",$bookings['datetime_from']);
                    //return date_time to only.....
                    $date_to = date("Y-m-d",$bookings['datetime_to']);
                    $time_to = date("H:i:s",$bookings['datetime_to']);
                    if($bookings['days_option'] == 1) {
                        $start = $date_from."T".$time_from;
                        $array[] = array('id' => $bookings['id'], 'title' => $driver['name'], 'start' => $start, 'allDay' => false);
                    } else {
                        $start = $date_from."T".$time_from;
                        $end = $date_to."T".$time_to;
                        $array[] = array('id' => $bookings['id'], 'title' => $driver['name'], 'start' => $start, 'end' => $end, 'allDay' => false);
                    }

                }

                $json = json_encode($array);
```

Now, my main file where it call this json file: I am adding only one line:

```
 eventSources: [

    // your event source
    {
        url: 'json_event.php', // use the `url` property

    }

    // any other sources...

],
```

So anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here as specially with my json file am I wrote correct or something missing.

Comment: thats why you never build your JSON string manually, just gives you headache. thats why `json_encode` exists

Comment: create an array and use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). By using this function you don't have to create manually te json string

Comment: Okay, then can you please tell me how I can write above php file to generate events and then use json_encode a bit new here in this case. thanks if you can rewrite my php file

Comment: He's not going to do your job for you :) He's given you the solution. It's simply a matter of using Google to identify the millions of examples of how to build PHP arrays and then call `json_encode` on them.

Comment: ok thanks I'll try to find something

Comment: Can you please tell me I update my json file but it's still not working can you tell me please?